# strange pycharm warning for list construction

Tags: python, list

I construct a list by the following codes:

```
[None for i in range(len_of_fields)]
```

But pycharm warns that: local variable *'i'* value is not used.
Yet the codes works quite good.

Is there anything wrong with my codes or just pycharm preference?

Comment: All your answers are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not actually used the `i` variable in your list comprehension, and so PyCharm thinks that you've done something wrong.

You can use `_` rather than `i`. In Python, `_` is generally taken to be *"a placeholder variable that I don't care about and can be safely ignored"* and I think PyCharm will respect this, i.e. it won't raise some warning.

Your list comprehension would then be

```
[None for _ in range(len_of_fields)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are using Python 2.x. In 2.x, the loop variables used in comprehensions, are leaked to the surrounding scope.

You can confirm that by doing

```
[None for i in range(len_of_fields)]
print i
```

It is fixed in Python 3.x, by creating a new function object for the comprehensions.

In your case, its best to do

```
[None] * len_of_fields
```

Answer (score 2):

You are really don't use "i" variable. You can suppress this warning by using placeholder "_" instead of unused "i".

```
[None for _ in range(len_of_fields)]
```